# Best practice to prevent sharing page url

Tags: wordpress, security, plugins

Looking for some strategy here. We have a secure (subscription-based) website that points to *another website* for streaming video. Currently, a savvy user could potentially share the link to the streaming page thus bypassing the login. Looking for ideas on how to:

1. Prevent sharing the link
2. Cloak the link...or
3. Make the link from the origin page point to a dynamically-generated URL that can only be visited once.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a form of streaming the video from the third party to your application (by streaming I actually mean sending the video in chunks of data to your backend, assembling them back together, and serving the actual assembled video as if it was hosted directly on the same host as the web application, I have personally done this using Amazon S3 for my open-source subscription-based CMS called [phpReel](https://github.com/phpreel/phpreel)) I don't think you can securely do this.

If you do want to go down this route please note that it might get expensive if you have a lot of active subscriptions but if you are interested you could check out [these files](https://github.com/phpreel/phpreel/tree/main/app/Helpers/Stream) as they showcase how I have done it for phpReel. I am afraid though that you might need a developer for this job.

On a more optimistic note, may I ask what service do you actually use to stream your videos? For example, Vimeo with the cheapest paid plan offers an option that restricts access to your video outside a specific domain name. Meaning you can set that your videos must be streamed only on domain.com, and thus they will be accessible there and only there.